# Taxation of shares

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, share-purchase-plan

If I purchase shares in my employer's business via share purchase plan, and those shares are bought directly from my **net** pay - do I need to pay tax on the money I receive when I sell those shares on the market?

Comment: If you make a profit from selling the shares, you will be liable for capital gains tax - but only if your gain exceeds your annual allowance ([currently £11,100](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/allowances)). This is unrelated to how you came by the shares in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @SteveMelnikoff if you care to write that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it :)

Comment: The Capital Gains Tax rate is either 18% or 28% depending on your income.  https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/work-out-your-capital-gains-tax-rate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [sell your shares](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-shares) for more than their value at the time you received them (i.e. you make a profit) then you will be liable for capital gains tax - but only if the profit exceeds your annual allowance ([£11,100, in tax year 2015-16](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/allowances)).

This is unrelated to how you came by the shares in the first place.

(Note that there are [certain exemptions](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-shares) to this, which includes some employer share schemes.)